# Firestore .startAt is not working properly

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

```
infiniteHandler($state) {
    var next = db
        .collection("posts")
        .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
        .startAfter(this.lastVisible)
        .limit(3)

    next.get().then(documentSnapshots => {
        //Get the last visible document
        // this.lastVisible =
        // documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1]

        if (documentSnapshots.docs.length == 0) $state.complete()
        else {
            this.$store.commit(
                "modules/posts/updateLastVisible",
                documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1].data()
                .timestamp
            )
        }

        documentSnapshots.forEach(doc => {
            var post = doc.data()
            post.docID = doc.id
            this.$store.commit("modules/posts/pushPost", post)
        })
        $state.loaded()
    })
}
```

This is my infinite loading handler which fetches new DB Entries once the end of the list is reached. Working fine so far.

This is my first fetch when the page gets loaded

```
async fetch({ store }){
    if (store.state.modules.posts.posts.length < 5) {
        let posts = []
        await db
            .collection("posts")
            .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
            .limit(3)
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                store.commit(
                    "modules/posts/updateLastVisible",
                    querySnapshot.docs[2].data().timestamp
                )
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    var x = doc.data()
                    x.docID = doc.id
                    posts.push(x)
                })
            })
        store.commit("modules/posts/fetchedPosts", posts)
    }
}
```

Basicly the problem is that I get the first 3 entries which I fetch on the page load again when I am fetching in my infinite Loading handler, which leads to the entries being displayed twice, this should not happen because `this.lastVisible` has the timestamp of the 3rd Element that I fetch on load, so those should be ignored.

After those elements everything is working fine with the `.startAfter` but the first 3 getting loaded again makes no sense. 
I checked the store with the devtools and everything is working fine, `this.lastVisible` has the correct value when the infiniteLoading Handler is called the first time.

Bounty Edit:
Okay so I still have the problem I tried to play around with it a bit more to find the issue but its still occuring... I will set a bounty now and I hope anyone is able to help.

Comment: I have a feeling this has to do with the infiniteHandler() running before this.lastVisible has been set. Try logging lastVisible at the top of the function.

Comment: @SeanRussell Sorry for the late response, yes indeed its logging an not valid object at the first time which leads to it basicly starting at the entry point of the whole list, but how could i change that behaviour?

Comment: Make your initial call in infaniteHandler(), it seems to be working after your first async fetch()

Comment: @SeanRussell but the infinitehandler shouldnt be able to work before the fetch is done no?

Comment: I meant adjust your logic/code to perform the action in one function. You said it works besides the first three documents being duplicated. Well, scrap the function that calls the first three documents.

Comment: @SeanRussell I cant simply but that away, the first 3 get fetched on Page Load so that they can get SSR, the infiniteHandler() is the only other function which gets called by a component once i reach a certain scroll point, I dont see a way to adjust it so the first 3 get fetched on the infiniteHandler(), i will try to make a condition that the infinitehandler doesnt execute before the this.LastVisible is populated.

Comment: @SeanRussell ok so my condition approach didnt work out because if i place a console.log after the `next` var is declared i still get the correct value out of `this.lastVisible` but somehow the query is not logging the right thing when called the first time, every code logic etc. is fine in my eyes so i cant see the problem

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually need the first time fetch. The infiniteHandler will be called on its own when it gets mounted. In case if it does not call then you can try using the function

> this.$refs.infiniteLoading.attemptLoad(); // 'infiniteLoading' is the component's ref property

That will actually invoke the infiniteHandler function for you.

EDIT: To check if one of the function is currently running. On the handler part

```
infiniteHandler($state) {
    //Check if its currently loading
    this.$nextTick(()=>{
       if (this.isDocSnapShotLoading){
           return;
       }
    });

    //set as currently loading
    this.isDocSnapShotLoading = true;

    var next = db
        .collection("posts")
        .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
        .startAfter(this.lastVisible)
        .limit(3)

    next.get().then(documentSnapshots => {
        //Get the last visible document
        // this.lastVisible =
        // documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1]

        if (documentSnapshots.docs.length == 0) $state.complete()
        else {
            this.$store.commit(
                "modules/posts/updateLastVisible",
                documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1].data()
                .timestamp
            )
        }

        documentSnapshots.forEach(doc => {
            var post = doc.data()
            post.docID = doc.id
            this.$store.commit("modules/posts/pushPost", post)
        })
        $state.loaded()

        //set completed loading
        this.isDocSnapShotLoading = false;
    })
}
```

On the fetch part

```
async fetch({ store }){
    if (store.state.modules.posts.posts.length < 5) {

        //check if currently loading
        this.$nextTick(()=>{
           if (this.isDocSnapShotLoading){
              return;
           }
       });

        //set as currently loading
        this.isDocSnapShotLoading = true;

        let posts = []
        await db
            .collection("posts")
            .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
            .limit(3)
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                store.commit(
                    "modules/posts/updateLastVisible",
                    querySnapshot.docs[2].data().timestamp
                )
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    var x = doc.data()
                    x.docID = doc.id
                    posts.push(x)
                })

                //set as completed loading.
                this.isDocSnapShotLoading = false;
            })
        store.commit("modules/posts/fetchedPosts", posts)
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I use my fetch logic of the Front Articles inside the infiniteHandler wouldnt this mean the content gets only fetched once the infiniteLoading is triggered? Even if i use your attempt to call it on page load I still dont have the benefits that fetch https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/ brings me in terms of SSR and speed

Comment: infiniteHandler is supposed to keep loading additional contents as you scroll down for more contents. So even if its called when the app is mounted it will keep getting called when you scroll down and if there are more contents.

Comment: I am not sure about the SSR part because you know your app structure and design better hence I cannot advise on that. If SSR does help your app then what you could do is maintain a store or component variable and set it to true when the fetch is working. In the infiniteHandler check this variable and prevent it from loading if its true.

Comment: Well fetch() is working because i display the 3 newest posts in Big Images on the frontpage, under that i have a infinite loading list, so the fetch itself if we talk about the same is working perfectly fine, the store is also populated with the right value that i pass to `startAfter()` so its hard for me make a simple workaround with value checking etc.

Comment: The post above has been edited above to add the checking. You can either use a component variable if the functions are in the same component. Otherwise you might need to add it as a store state.

Comment: Hey thanks for the effort but this still does not work and it still fetches the first 3 posts again

Comment: An edit has been made to the loading checking part of the code. Can you try if that works?

Comment: Sure I will test it out once Im home

Comment: I didn´t forget you but I am working on other Parts of the Page right now, but i´ll get sure to answer you back once I found a solution and tested your approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanto be ignore first 3 posts in infiniteHandler then, you can make one post array where you store post id and check whether post id is already loaded or not. I know this should be solved using query but as temporary solution I hope it will work for you.

```js
infiniteHandler($state) {
    var next = db
        .collection("posts")
        .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
        .startAfter(this.lastVisible)
        .limit(3)

    next.get().then(documentSnapshots => {
        //Get the last visible document
        // this.lastVisible =
        // documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1]

        if (documentSnapshots.docs.length == 0) $state.complete()
        else {
            this.$store.commit(
                "modules/posts/updateLastVisible",
                documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1].data()
                .timestamp
            )
        }

        documentSnapshots.forEach(doc => {
            var check = this.postIdArray.indexOf(doc.id);
            if(check == -1){
                var post = doc.data()
                post.docID = doc.id
                this.$store.commit("modules/posts/pushPost", post);
                this.postIdArray[] = doc.id;
            }
        })
        $state.loaded()
    })
}



async fetch({ store }){
    this.postIdArray = [];
    if (store.state.modules.posts.posts.length < 5) {
        let posts = []
        await db
            .collection("posts")
            .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
            .limit(3)
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
                store.commit(
                    "modules/posts/updateLastVisible",
                    querySnapshot.docs[2].data().timestamp
                )
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    var x = doc.data()
                    x.docID = doc.id
                    this.postIdArray[] = doc.id;
                    posts.push(x)
                })
            })
        store.commit("modules/posts/fetchedPosts", posts)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea but I wanna start it clean without stuff like that but if nothing else will help then i probably need something like this...

Comment: Have you check your this.lastVisible is updating and getting proper values in it?

Comment: Yes I did that via console.log in the infinite loader and via the vuex devtools, all I see is that when I log the `next` variable in my infiniteloading that it looks different the first time its called compared to the other times, while the same values are passed to it ...

Comment: Are you sure that infiniteHandler is only calling after user is read to page end and after first call is complete, As per my understanding what is happening first time there is not any content so directly  infiniteHandler and first call are calling simultaneously  so data is same first time and after problem is resolved.

Comment: Sadly im not home so I can´t test it out right now but I will check that when im home and send you a message again

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a temporary solution which works for now but is still not pretty:

```
documentSnapshots.forEach(doc => {
          if (
            doc.id !== this.posts[0].docID &&
            doc.id !== this.posts[1].docID &&
            doc.id !== this.posts[2].docID
          ) {
            var post = doc.data()
            post.docID = doc.id
            this.$store.commit("modules/posts/pushPost", post)
          }
        })
```

I also try to make this more efficient with different solutions, thanks so far for your help.